# change file name when filter changes in Windows file save dialog from c++

Tags: c++, winapi

In a Windows Save File dialog, I would like to automatically change the extension part of the filename in the edit box when the user changes the filter.  That is, if the user is saving an image file, and changes the type to JPEG, the file name automatically changes to .jpg.

IIRC this used to be possible via hooks but that approach is no longer supported.  Is there a way to accomplish it now?  I'm using C++ (C++Builder if it makes any difference).

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK hook approach ist still supported for _old_ common dialogs library, if you're targeting Windows Vista+ just change your code to use `IFileOpenDialog`. You can attach a listener via `IFileDialog.Advise()` and get/set file name with `IFileDialog.GetFileName()` and `IFileDialog.SetFileName()`.

Comment: Are you using the VCL wrapper for the dialog? Do you need to support both old and new style dialogs?

Comment: We typically use the VCL wrappers (C++Builder 2009).  I think we have some users will on XP, so we should support both if possible.